# React: this.state vs this.setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Scenario 1:

```
const { foo } = this.state;
```

Scenario 2:

```
this.setState(({ foo }) => { ... });
```

is `foo` guaranteed to be identical between these two cases?  Or will `setState` ever run async and return a different value based on other `setState`s?

Answer (score 2):

State might be state when you access the state immediately after using `this.setState`, as `this.setState` is `async`.

If you need to compute on basis on the updated state i.e ( after `this.state` is invoked ), you can use the 2nd argument for the method which is a callback that gets triggered after the state changes are committed.

```
this.setState(updateState, () => {
   const { foo } = this.state;

   console.log(foo); // updated foo
});

function updatedState({ foo }) { 
    // you can be sure that `foo`
    // is from the previous state 
    // before setState is called
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the [**React docs**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) mention:

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied.

So we can use the second argument of the **`setState`** to pass a callback where we execute our logic which depends on having the updated value of foo. However your initial question was whether the value of foo in `const { foo } = this.state;` and the value of foo in `this.setState(({ foo }) => { ... });` was the same.

In order check this we can compare executing a **`setState`** followed by **`this.state.foo`** and a **`setState`** followed by another **`setState`** (the second one will just log the value of foo instead of mutating it). Please refer to the following snippet:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      foo: 0,
      boo: 0
    }
  }
  
  handleClickSetState = () => {
    this.setState(({foo}) => ({foo: foo+1}));
    this.setState(({foo}) => console.log("inside setState. foo: ", foo));
  }
  
  handleClickState = () => {
    this.setState(({boo}) => ({boo: boo+1}));
    console.log("outside setState. boo: ", this.state.boo)
  }
  
  render() {
    return <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={this.handleClickState}>Test state</button>
      <button onClick={this.handleClickSetState}>Test setState</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

As we can see the "state case" lags behind by 1, which we would expect since **`setState`** is async (and we didn't use the second argument of **`setState`**). However the "setState case" shows that the correct value is always shown, even if we don't utilize the second argument callback in setState.

In conclusion `const { foo } = this.state;` will always give you the immediate value of foo, regardless of pending state merges, while `this.setState(({ foo }) => { ... });` seems like it will first finish pending updates before executing the callback, which means foo will always have the most recent value.

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is async, and pulling values off state to use in `setState` is a potential source of bugs. `setState` can take multiple arguments. It can take just a new state, a callback that takes old state + props and returns new state, new state and a function to run after setting new state, or a combination. Example:

```
this.setState(
  // function taking previous state + props,
  // which should return updated state.
  // this could also just be an object with
  // the new state, if you don't need to rely
  // on previous state.
  (previousState, props) => {
    if (previousState.something) {
      return { something: somethingElse }
    } else {
      return { something: anotherThing }
    }
  }, () => {
    // safe to use new state here,
    // since state has been updated.
    // but it's recommended to use
    // componentDidUpdate instead!
  })
```